# Ошибка using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported (XCode)

Tags: swift, xcode

У меня есть проект `XCode (Swift)`, в котором используется статическая библиотека (Swift), и эта библиотека использует другую статическую библиотеку (C++)

> статическая библиотека A (C++) -> статическая библиотека B (Swift) -> MyProject (Swift)

Чтобы иметь возможность использовать методы из библиотеки `A` в библиотеке `B`, мне нужно установить файл `bridge` в `BuildSettings`, верно? тогда я могу использовать любые методы из `A` в `B`, хорошо.

Если я пробую собрать библиотеку `B` с `Build libraries for distribution = NO`, все компилируется и работает, но если мне нужно изменить это значение на `YES` (чтобы собрать библиотеку как Release ver), я получаю ошибку

> error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported

Я поискал и нашел несколько возможных решений на SO, где большинство из них предлагают установить `Build libraries for distribution = NO`, но это больше похоже на костыль так как для того, чтоб собраль либу в релизе нужно установить значение как `YES`.

Затем я нашел другое решение

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/10419

но здесь объясняется, что

> You'll need to remove the bridging header from where you added it in the Build Settings, in order to get your framework to compile.

Но я не могу удалить файл `bridge`, потому что тогда я не смогу использовать методы из `А` в `В`.

Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: насколько я знаю, bridging header нужен только для взаимодействия swift с objective c или с/с++, если у вас обе библиотеки на чистом свифте, то он не нужен

Comment: @schmidt9 добавил в вопрос изменения, там одна либа свифт и вторая с++

Comment: рассматривали ли вы вариант преобразования библиотеки А в динамический фреймворк? По крайней мере у меня при таком решении удалось скомпилировать библиотеку Б с `Build libraries for distribution = YES` и подключить обе библиотеки к проекту

Comment: @schmidt9 динамический фреймворк вы имеете ввиду dll? Нет, эта либа должна быть статической

Comment: я имею в виду `Mach-O Type = Dynamic Library`, но да, смысл тот же, в любом случае кроме bridging header можно попробовать подключить С++ через modulemap (например https://stackoverflow.com/a/29189873/3004003), правда для статической либы мне не удалось настроить работу с модулями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем в итоге я сделал это через `modulemap` файл

Я убрал ссылки на bridge файл (в Build Settings) и сделал вот такой modulemap для `.h`

```
module LibA {
    header "LibA.h"
    export *
}
```

который положил рядом с `.h` файлом

И теперь перед использованием методов либы в каком то файле мне нужно написать `import LibA` и тогда методы доступны и проблема с bridge файлом не возникает

Спасибо @kun wang за вот этот ответ
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68980854/5709159